# ringcentral-web-phone is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, express, ringcentral

Just trying to implement a basic calling app with audio included.

Im having issues with https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-web-phone. It says that the way to invoke an instance is

```
new RingCentral.WebPhone(..., {...})
```

In real code, im importing it like this:

```
const  RingCentralWebPhone = require('ringcentral-web-phone')
// ...
rcWebPhone = new RingCentralWebPhone(sipProvision, {...})
```

When running it tells me that

RingCentralWebPhone is not a constructor

Im stuck with this I would really appreciate the help.

Im using express to run it in localhost.

Comment: I think it should be like this.
`const  RingCentral = require('ringcentral-web-phone')`
`rcWebPhone = new RingCentral.WebPhone(sipProvision, {...})`

Comment: @Thusitha it still appears the same error